# How to set the libraries global for all the functions?

Tags: python, function, global

I have a main file from which I call some functions, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/myFolder/')
from myFunction import myFun1, muFun2, myFun3
```

However when I run the function I received the following error

```
tmp = myFun1(x,y)
NameError: global name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid importing the modules?

Comment: You can't do that. For one thing, it makes your code much less readable, as I can't see within `myFunction` where `np` is coming from.

Comment: I don't want to avoid importing the modules, I just want to import them once.

Comment: That means you have a function, in `myfunction`, that uses `np`, but you never `import np` into that file. Even if this is possible (I don't think so, but not positive), it's definitely not a maintainable way to set up your code. What if someone else does `import myOwnLib as np`, should everything break horribly now?

Comment: Python is smart enough to only import once. If you `import np` into `myFunction` and then import `myFunction` in whatever script you have, you'll only actually do the import once

Comment: If the number of imports you have to repeat is truly excessive, you may have too many dependencies, or you may have split your own code into too many modules. In any case, trying to delegate imports like you want is a bad idea.

Comment: yes `myFunction` uses ` np`. I do not know why there is not a way to define it globally.

Comment: You've been told that. What is still confusing?

Answer (score 1):

You could kind of achieve what you want, but you'd have to bypass the normal import system in python and basically just "source" either the central import file or the function files.

*a.py*

```
def func():
    np.something()
```

*b.py*

```
import numpy as np
execfile('/path/to/a.py')

func()
```

`execfile` allows you to basically take the contents of one python file and run them within the current python file, as if the functions had been declared in `b.py`.

You could also do the reverse -- put all your imports in a single file and then `execfile` that file at the top of all your other python files.

That being said, you probably shouldn't do this, but python is flexible enough to allow you to dig yourself into a hole if you want to.

Comment: Note that `execfile` is python 2 only.